# How to fix mypy "has no attribute" error, while class has that attribute

Tags: python, mypy

I'm really new to python so maybe I'm asking an obvious question. The error returned by mypy is:

```
automaxlair\matchup_scoring.py:57: error: "Pokemon" has no attribute "ability_name_id"
```

Indeed, line 57 of matchup_scoring.py, I'm doing that : EDIT : added more lines before line 57 to show definition of method

```
def ability_damage_multiplier(attacker: Pokemon, move_index: int,
    defender: Pokemon
) -> float:
    """Return a damage multiplier stemming from abilities."""

    # Account for abilities that affect the damage of certain move types.
    if attacker.ability_name_id not in ('mold-breaker', 'turboblaze', 'teravolt'):
```

At the beginning of matchup_scoring.py, I'm doing

```
from automaxlair import pokemon_classes
Pokemon = TypeVar('Pokemon')
```

in the imported file (automaxlair\pokemon_classes.py), I have :

```
class Pokemon():
    def __init__(self,
        ability_name_id: str
    ):
        self.ability_name_id = ability_name_id
```

Could someone explain to me what is wrong ? It does that for all other attribute of Pokemon so I only picked one. I'm using python 3.8 if that matter

Thanks in advance !

Comment: What is this attacker object and from where it is coming? can you post that part of code?

Comment: sure ! I just edited my message. It's inside a function and attacker is of Pokemon type

Comment: I think the problem can be the `Pokemon = TypeVar('Pokemon')` code, because can be confused with the class, where are you instanciating `attacker` and `defender`? Anyway `TypeVar` is usually used for generics, but I don't see any there

Comment: Why do you declare ``Pokemon = TypeVar('Pokemon')``? This just means you have a *variable for a type*, and that variable is named ``Pokemon``. It does not mean you have a *variable of type ``Pokemon``*. It appears what you want is just ``attacker: pokemon_classes.Pokemon`` (and similar for other pokemon values).

Comment: Oh okay, so it was the issue indeed. I thought I needed to do that to create List[Pokemon] but it turns out I didn't ! Thanks a lot !